# How to include multiple JS files are dependent on the event onload or $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

There are several libraries that are in different files, some of them must be included at the same time onload event. Convenience that I can call only the library that I need. sometimes I need to block access to including file.

That's what I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=JS;?>swfupload/swfupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=JS;?>swfupload/handlers.<?=$language;?>.js"></script>

<!-- ACTION -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $.getScript("<?=JS;?>swfupload/swfupload.action.js");
      $.getScript("<?=JS;?>maps/gmap3.action.js");
      $.getScript("<?=JS;?>tiny_mce/tiny_mce.action.js");
      $.getScript("/jvs/cabinet.company.js");

  });

</script>

<!-- tinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=JS;?>tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
```

But I don't like using $.getScript method, some events are not processed by Ajax.
Please help solve the problem.

Comment: Why must some of them be included via the onload event?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what is best to use to include Java Script code, but in each of the initialization source code is called from the onload event or $(document).ready({...});

Comment: If I don't do it by onload event, then some of these scripts will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just use the done and fail functions, like this:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

Or just use a standard Ajax request, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

It's covered in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/